# How can I see the NPU cores?

Tags: activity-monitor, system-information

NPU cores don't show up in system information or Activity Monitor.  Is there a way to see their utilization -- something like nvidia-smi or nv-top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - check out [asitop](https://github.com/tlkh/asitop).

It shows CPU/GPU/ANE (NPU) usage statistics, as well as power utilization. It uses `powermetrics` to gather some of this information.